# Dynamically Adding Category Specific Content To Specific Category & Subcategory Pages

Tags: categories, page-template

I'm working on an internal project/idea (a directory of sorts for a vertical market) where I will have 40 Categories with each Category having (potentially) 30 Sub-Categories.

For each Category and Sub-Category page we need to present (unique for each Cat and Sub-Cat) a block of rich text (and possibly an image) in the top of the first page, and some additional text in the bottom of the first page. Subsequent pages in the page-navi would just have standard Category (or Sub-Category) title.

The text in the bottom of the page would be updated from time to time - so (relatively) easy content management would be ideal.

I know I can create a conditional statement above the loop in a category.php page template to place the various text elements -- but that's one monster conditional statement.  And I obviously don't want to create a unique category template for each.

I'd rank myself an intermediate WP coder so I'm wondering if any of you Pro's have some insight. I'm not looking for code, just a general sense of best practice/strategy for how I might approach this so it's easy to manage through the WP Admin (ideally) going forward. Looking for a point in the right direction.

I just can't seem to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly then this shouldn't be too hard and i would suggest using this [Taxonomy Meta Script](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/taxonomy-meta-script-for-wordpress.html) to simply add a rich editor , an image field and anything else you need for each category , this would make your life easier.

Comment: Much appreciated. That's exactly the info I was looking for.